# Formula.recalculateFormulas() in Before Trigger: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, Cannot set the value of a calculated field

Tags: apex, trigger, formula, before-trigger

I want to enforce recalculation of all records in `trigger.new` and I want to do it in a "before" trigger:

```
trigger AnyTrigger on AnySObject__c (before insert, before update) { 
    Formula.recalculateFormulas( trigger.new );
}
```

This produces the following run-time exception

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
> a0B0Y00000J4sjGUAR; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, Cannot set the
> value of a calculated field: []

I checked the [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Formula.htm) but it seems kind of poor and was not helpful.

I found this article here https://katiekodes.com/recalculate-formulas-salesforce-apex/
The workaround is to

- clone all the records of trigger.new and put the clones into a list
- execute Formula.recalculateFormulas() on the list of clones instead on trigger.new
- use the formulas from the clones to drive the logic on trigger.new

Even if it works, I don't like this approach. It costs memory and time and the triggers are already close to the limits and I need to keep the footprint as small as possible.

**Questions**

- is there any official documentation why we can't do this in a before-trigger context?
- is there a better workaround or a different approach to make the formulas recalculate in this example?

Comment: I linked an older version of the question, it's got some history. As far as we outsiders know, it's a bug. This is particularly telling, because you're getting an UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION rather than a more specific exception that would happen (QueryException, DmlException, something). The workaround is the best that you can reasonably do. You may want to report this as a bug, though, but I'll ask for clarification from on high, just to be sure.

Comment: Bug W-10128616 was created for you. If you want to open a case, reference that number.

Comment: I've taken it a step further as well can had a Known Issue created so you can skip the bug step https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002CEn8QAG